# How can I set the MaxLength of a TextBox to Infinite?

Tags: c#, winforms

By default, the value of `MaxLength` is `32676`. How can I set this value to no limit, or infinite?

Comment: Read the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx

Comment: Set it to 0, which means no limit.

Comment: @Taw: 0 means `the maximum number of characters the user can enter is 2147483646 or an amount based on available memory, whichever is smaller.` I would not call that no limit, although it's plenty huge.

Comment: @TaW Please post an answer.

Comment: MSDN: `The maximum number of characters that can be manually entered into the text box. The default is 0, which indicates no limit. (..) When this property is set to 0, the maximum length of the text that can be entered in the control is limited only by available memory.`

Comment: @TaW: that's the doc on the WPF TextBox MaxLength property. Title has 'Windows Forms application' in it.

Comment: @ChristopheD my bad. But for all practical purposes.. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it to `0`. From the [documentation on MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx):

> **Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows 2000 Server, Windows 2000 Advanced Server, Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003 Platform Note:** If the MaxLength property is set to 0, the maximum number of characters the user can enter is 2147483646 or an amount based on available memory, whichever is smaller.
>
> **Windows Millennium Edition Platform Note:** If the MaxLength property is set to 0, the maximum number of characters the user can enter is 32,766 or an amount based on available memory, whichever is smaller.

So while infinite isn't possible, slightly more than 2 billion characters ought to be enough.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming a WinForms TextBox) Since [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is [Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you will only be able to bring it to `Int32.MaxValue`.

That's quite a lot actually (2,147,483,647). Do you really need it to be *infinite*? Then you are better off using a custom control (which you  may very well derive from one of the existing ones, off course).